# PHP Error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, oop, static

```
    public static function assign($name, $value)
    {
        $this->params[] = array($name => $value);
    }

    public static function draw()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }
}


<?php
    $test = Templater::assign('key', 'value')->draw();
    print_r($test);
```

I need to function "assign" was static, but $params was common for the whole class..
But this code is not working.

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton would work nice here

```
class Templater {
  private static $instance = null;
  private $params = array();

  public function __construct(){
    return $this;
  }

  public static function instance(){
    if(is_null(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new self();
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function assign($name, $value){
    $this->params[$name] = $value;
    return $this;
  }

  public function draw(){
    return $this->params;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$test = Templater::instance()
  ->assign('var1', 'value1')
  ->assign('var2', 'value2')
  ->draw();
print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want `$params` to be `static`:

```
<?php
class Templater
{
    static $params = array();

    public static function assign($name, $value)
    {
        self::$params[] = array($name => $value);
    }

    public static function draw()
    {
        return self::$params;
    }
}


<?php
    Templater::assign('key', 'value');
    $test = Templater::draw();
    print_r($test);
```

Comment: Another error: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function draw() on a non-object in

Comment: You were calling ->draw(). I missed that. I've edited to correct.

Comment: $test = Templaters::assign('key', 'value')->assign('key2', 'value2')->draw();
How do I make it so I could use this code this way?

Comment: You have to completely eliminate static methods and properties in your code. See my sample below.

Answer (score 2):

`$this` keyword refers to the class instance. When you are trying to call it inside a static method no class instance is used. So your `assign` method cannot be static to interact with `$params`, that is not static. Make `$params` static, or `assign` dynamic (not static).

```
<?php
class Templater
{
    static var $params = array();

    public static function assign($name, $value)
    {
        $this->params[] = array($name => $value);
    }

    public static dunction draw()
    {
        return self::params;
    }
}
```

or:

```
<?php
class Templater
{
    var $params = array();

    public function assign($name, $value)
    {
        $this->params[] = array($name => $value);
    }

    public dunction draw()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }
}
```

Both will work, but you must to choose the one that is more adequate for your application's design.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `$params` to be a static field, use:

```
class Templater {
  private static $params = array();

  public static function assign($name, $value) {
    self::params[] = array($name => $value);
  }

  public static dunction draw() {
    return self::params;
  }
}
```

`static` functions have no `$this` context.

By the way, don't use `var` for declaring instance variables. That's PHP4. Do it the PHP5 way.